# Can't get a response back when using localhost on Asp.net web API and postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I was attempting to run my asp.net web API project in debug mode and then call it from postman. I tried calling the default api values controller but my request keeps timing out saying it cant reach the server:

**Values Controller:**

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

**Postman response:**

[image]

**Web Browser Help Page:**

[image]

Is there some additional setup I need to do? Or common issues related to this?

Comment: you will need to turn off the SSL certificate verification in Postman. Go to Settings in Postman, off the SSL certificate verification in General Tab.

Comment: Your browser shows it's connecting to `https://localhost`, not `http://localhost`.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that right as you posted the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be fixed if you do the ssl certificate offline from Settings.
[image: Settings]

[image: SSL certificate verification: OFF]